# Value in python dictionary changes unintentionally even when dictionary was not referenced

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get a value from dictionary A, but somehow, through the 4th line(with the arrow), that changes the value of dictionary B.

(`dictA` value is a dictionary of dictionary,`something` is a float,
`KWresults` is a lists in a list, `a` is a list)

```py
results = []
for a in results:
    something = dictA.get(a)
    a.append(something)   # <--------------------
    results.append(a)
```

To get `KWresults`, I iterated through `dictB` to get the relevant data, but at no point in time did ever have code in the format of

```
dictB['something']=something
```

After testing, it is the append line (the one in arrow) where by `dictB` changes. The value of `dictB` is a list, and after the append line, the list has the variable `something` appended to it. I was wondering if anyone knew why the value of my dictionary changed when `dictB` was never referenced in this particular line.

Comment: Could you include the code that created `dictA` and `dictB` please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem lies in your expectation of how Python objects behave.
Python objects are accessed by reference, so if your object is shared in different data structures, modifying it will affect all these structures regardless whether you explicitly reference the object by its name, or otherwise.

Consider the following example:

```python
import copy

list1 = [1, 2, 3]

# Both dict1 and dict2 share the same list1 object:
dict1 = {1: list1}
dict2 = {1: [], 2: list1}

# Modifying list1 affects all objects sharing it by reference:
dict1[1].append(4)
print(dict2)
# Prints
# {1: [], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4]}

# Alternatively, we can copy just the data by using copy.deepcopy, serializing and then
# deserializing, etc. Cf:
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
dict1 = copy.deepcopy({1: list1})
dict2 = copy.deepcopy({1: [], 2: list1})

dict1[1].append(4)
print(dict2)
# Now prints
# {1: [], 2: [1, 2, 3]}
```

In the first approach, `dict1[1]` points to `list1`, so modifying it essentially modifies `list1`, effectively changing `dict2[2]` (since it is a yet another reference to `list1`).

In the second part of the example, we explicitly perform a "deep" copy of the data to new objects, so they are not shared between the two `dict`s.

Comment: Does this only happen to dictionaries?

Comment: No, it happens (almost) everywhere you reference a Python object. Consider the following example: `>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3]] * 4; my_list[1][1] = 7`. Question: what is the value of `my_list` now?

Comment: ah i see, thank you so much, had no idea about this caveat about python objects