# Updating a one dictionary updates a value of another in a different way; only when updated using tf.keras.optimizers.get function but not otherwise

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary

There are two dictionaries: `a` and `b`. `b` is created using `a`, but it does not point to the same object as `a`. (`a is b` returns `False`)

I have observed that when I update a value in `b`: it changes the corresponding value of `a` (not by the same update that happened in `b` though). What's more troubling is that, this is only observed when using the [`tf.keras.optimizers.get`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/get)  function to update `b`. When used some other method to update `b`, this behavior is not observed.

Also, the change applied to a `b`'s element isn't applied to `a`'s corresponding element, but rather an augmentation of `a`'s corresponding element is resulted - a lower cased dictionary value, while no `lowercase()` function was applied.

## Reproducible example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = {
    "x": 1,
    'y': {
        'class_name': 'Adam',
        'config': {
            'learning_rate': 0.0001
        }
    }
}  # a['y'] can be passed as an input to tf.keras.optimizers.get
b = {key: value for key, value in a.items()}

print(a)  # b also looks the same
# {'x': 1,
#  'y': {'class_name': 'Adam', 'config': {'learning_rate': 0.0001}}}
```

Update the `'y'` value of `b`:

```
b['y'] = tf.keras.optimizers.get(b['y'])
```

As expected, `b` is changed:

```
print(b)
# {'x': 1,
#  'y': <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam at 0x7f5656476090>}
```

But, this has also changed the value of `a['y']['class_name']` to lower case!

```
print(a)
# {'x': 1,
#  'y': {'class_name': 'adam', 'config': {'learning_rate': 0.0001}}}
```

But no change is observed in `a` when `b['x']` is updated like below:

```
b['x'] = b['x'] * 2

print(a)
# {'x': 1,
#  'y': {'class_name': 'adam', 'config': {'learning_rate': 0.0001}}}

print(b)
# {'x': 2,
 'y': <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam at 0x7f44374ad610>}
```

Why is it so? How to avoid it?

**Edit 1:**

After comments about shallow copy:

```
a['x'] is b['x'], a['y'] is b['y']
# (True, True)  # Edit 1.1 - executed just after the definitions of a and b
```

**Edit 2:**

Regarding the Close vote:

I do not understand why `a['y']['class_name']` went from `'Adam'` to `'adam'` (lower case). This is not discussed in the suggested duplicate.

No `lowercase()` function was applied to any of the elements in either dictionary.

Comment: Note, `b = {key: value for key, value in a.items()}` is an overly complicated way of writing `b = dict(a)`. In any case, you are creating a *shallow copy* of `a`.

Comment: It’s a feature; when you copy the y value from a to be they still reference the same dictionary and if you change either the other reference will of course reflect that change.

Comment: Seach for copy.deepcopy in the documentation - this is one way of making new dictionaries.

Comment: @barny: `.. if you change either the other reference will of course reflect that change` - this isn't happening here!  `b['x'] = b['x'] * 2` hasn't affected `a['x']`, but `b['y'] = tf.keras.optimizers.get(b['y'])` has made `a['y']['class_name']` to lower case (`'Adam'` -> `'adam'`, it's not even the same change that `b['y']` got; `b['y']` became `<tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam at 0x7f44374ad610>`

Comment: The `x` value is an integer, immutable; the same would happen for a string. But dictionaries and lists are mutable and if you want to not refer to the same object you have to consciously create a new object using `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67147408/value-in-python-dictionary-changes-unintentionally-even-when-dictionary-was-not

Comment: @barny Thank you for the links! I still can't grasp how `'Adam'` became `'adam'` though. Can you explain that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you! Please check `Edit: 1`. Now, with that output, I do not understand two things: 1). `b['x'] = b['x'] * 2` hasn't changed `a['x']` while `a['x'] is b['x']` is `True`, 2). While `a['y'] is b['y']` returned `False`, changing `b['y']` has applied an unrelated function to `a['y']` (changing `'Adam'` to `'adam'`).

Comment: Sorry, I should've executed them at the beginning. See Edit 1.1, it returns `True, True` when executed just after the definitions of `a` and `b`.